# How to assign generated primary key value in different column on same entity

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm looking for solution to reuse the generated primary key value in the same object. My entity object code given below,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "primaryKeyGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "primaryKeyGenerator", strategy = "com.id.generator.CustomGenerator")
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="version")
private int version=0;

@Column(name="object_tuple_id")
private Long objectTypleId;


@Column(name="owner_id")
private Long ownerId;
```

I want to use the generated id value in ownerId object. Is this possible?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

What are you exactly trying to do? Do you want it to use the same generator when saving a new instance of the entity, are you trying to map two field to the same column or are you trying to make the default value of ownerId to be the same as the id when first saving a new instance of the entity.

For the last one I suggest not making things too complicated  (if this won't cause concurrency issues for you to just):

```
session.saveOrUpdate(yourNewObject);
session.merge(yourNewObject);
yourNewObject.setOwnerId(youNewObject.getId());
session.saveOrUpdate(youNewObject);
```